# Java Double getting initialized to 0.0

Tags: java, double

I have a bean where I have a field "CustAmount "which is double, I tried testing the bean and i dont seem to understand this: When i run on my local machine it gets initialized to 0.0 when instantiated. When i run the same code in my linux test environment it remains null. due to which there is a difference in the retrieved data meaning if i send the CustAmount as null to my Backend i get some data but if i send the CustAmount as 0.0 the query is done on the basis of 0.0 and sends me nothing back.

How is this possible if the code is same, By any chance is it possible that when i do new MyBean() compiled in java 1.5 the double remains null and in 1.6 it gets initialized to 0.0.

I dont know if this is something that happens in two Java versions but thats the only difference on my end.

Thanks for any hint.

Adding code snippet :

```
public class MyBean {

private double custAmount;

    public void setCustAmount(double custAmount) {
        this.custAmount = custAmount;
    }
public double getCustAmount() {
        return custAmount;
    }

}
```

And I just do

```
MyBean mybean =  new MyBean();
```

its not a Double but a double.
Syed..

Comment: Some small piece of code which reproduces this, will help:)

Comment: This will have nothing to do with Java versions and everything to do with server environment. Presumably this is a web application: are you running the same version of the same server on both machines?

Comment: @PetarMinchev Its a simple new MyBean()  that the double gets the value 0.0 so there is not much code

Comment: 1) *"there is not much code"* **For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).** 2) A `CustAmount` field should be `custAmount`. I'm not sure if the exact case is important for beans, but I'd recommend changing it.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill yes this is a web application, yes the servers are the same I am running websphere 7 and the test env is also running the same version.

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry it was a typo on my end

Comment: @sarmahdi Copy/paste is more useful than apology.  ;)

Comment: We need at least a definition of the double field, any setters/getters and how you send/retrieve it. Without any code (ideally a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)) it's hard to help you. As a general rule: the more effort you put into your question the more effort people will put into their answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A Java `double` field will be default initialized to `0.0`.  A Java `Double` field will be default initialized to `null`.  These two facts will be true no matter what version of Java you use, and no matter what environment you run it in.

---

If you are seeing different behavior in different environments, then the most likely explanation is that you are executing DIFFERENT code in the respective environments (or calling the same code in different ways).  Posting some code that exhibits the problem *may* point to some other problem, but I doubt it.

---

Based on your posted code, it is IMPOSSIBLE for `custAmount` to be `null`.  In the case where you are seeing a `null`, you must be EITHER using a different version of that code, OR the `null` must be coming from some other source.

Comment: And, a `double` cannot be null since it is a primitive. I agree with Stephen, you're probably running different code.

Comment: the code was the same. but there was some XSL transformation done and there the double was handled differently and my XSL wasnt updated. So yes in a sense my code was different.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I thought my Long initializes to 0. But it wasn't initialized itself, but from the `<p:selectOneMenu />` on my page.

```
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.myLongValue}">
                <f:selectItem value="#{null}" itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-" />
                <f:selectItems ... />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
```

So, try to check your page, if you are not setting it somehow from your form.